# slideDown/slideUp AND Rotate an Image

Tags: jquery, css

I've recently taken over a project with a lot of custom js. One of the things that I'm working on is a stacked menu that expands down - it's essentially an accordion - but it's written a little differently. What I have is a chevron icon that rotates 90 degrees when the item is opened, then rotates back when the item is closed. I've got this working great:

```
{
    this.subj.find(".category .ctitle").click(
        function()
        {
            $(this).children(".gold-ra").toggleClass("down");
            if($(this).next(".tlists").is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next(".tlists").slideUp("slow");

            } else {
               $(this).next(".tlists").slideDown("slow");
            }
```

However, the issue I'm running into is that if a user were to click before the slide action is complete, the chevron rotation becomes out of sync with the item opening an closing (i.e. it points down when the item is closed).

[image]

I've tried toggling the image rotation with the slide, but that does not prevent the issue. I've even eliminated the slide and changed to show and hide, but no dice their, either.

I'm using CSS to rotate the image with the class down. Is there a better way to achieve the desired syncing of the slide and rotation?

```
.gold-ra {
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: url("/view/liveassets/svg/RightArrowG.svg")no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms linear;
    transition: all 100ms linear;
    height: 17px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}

.gold-ra.down {
         -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
        transform:rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: top center;
        position: relative;
        top: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling `.down` before your if/else logic can cause your issue. Since you already have logic to handle which accordions open you can add the add and remove logic for the chevron in there as well.

```
if($(this).next(".tlists").is(":visible")) {
  $(this).next(".tlists").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).children(".gold-ra").removeClass("down");
} else {
  $(this).next(".tlists").slideDown("slow");
  $(this).children(".gold-ra").addClass("down");
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. All the up votes to @Wild Beard.